# What I am missing to make my custom UITableView cell work?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I created a custom cell in the following way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    FacilityResult* currentResult = [_facilityResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"facilityResultDesign" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

When creating the FacilityResult object, which is the class for the custom cell I update the labels as follows:

```
@implementation FacilityResult


- (id)initWithModel:(NSString *)name city:(NSString*)city zipcode:(NSString*)zipcode facility_id:(NSString*)facility_id{
    _name = name;
    _zipcode = zipcode;
    _city = city;
    _facility_id = facility_id;
    return self;
}

- (id)initwithModel:(NSMutableDictionary*)propertyDictionary{
    if (![[propertyDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"name"])
        NSLog(@"Error: Cell Object does not have a name");
    else{
        _name = propertyDictionary[@"name"];
        [propertyDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        [_nameField setText:_name];
    }
    if (![[propertyDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"city"])
        NSLog(@"Error: Cell Object does not have a city");
    else{
        _city= propertyDictionary[@"city"];
        [propertyDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"city"];
        [_cityField setText:_city];
    }
return self;
}


@end
```

-Updated ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [[login getSearchFacility] setDelegate:self];
   [_resultTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FacilityRow" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"facilityResultDesign"];
   if(_facilityResults==nil)
       _facilityResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

However, the cells labels don't update "Some Company" is the default name I entered for the label on xcode. It is supposed to update to name1.
[image]

Comment: please press on button on xib editor "Show document outline" for show all tree views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a cell in a xib file, you should register the nib, not the class (only register the class if you make the cell entirely in code). You should do the registering in viewDidLoad. The method, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: is guaranteed to return a cell, so your if (cell == nil) clause will never be entered, that's why doing the registering there has no effect.

Comment: I agree, it never enters the if cell==nil. How do I register the xib then? Thanks

Comment: @Alon_T, like I said in my answer. Do it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: what function do I use? I'm really not sure

Comment: @Alon_T, just move the code you have in the if cell==nil clause to viewDidLoad: [_resultTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"facilityResult" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"facilityResultDesign"]; (but notice you need to use _resultTable instead of tableView).

Comment: I did it, but now it crashes in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with the reason of: `Could not load NIB in bundle...with the name "facilityResult"`

Comment: Is the NIB name the name of the file?

Comment: @Alon_T, I can't see why you get that error, but the reason you still see what looks like the default cell overtop your custom one, is that you're populating cell.textLabel instead of your custom labels. You should have IBOutlets to the labels in your custom cell, and populate those in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60335/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-alon-t).